# Custom controls (groupbox, picturebox, label) - On Mouse Enter, Insides Disappear

Tags: .net, vb.net, groupbox

Sorry for that very confusing title, here's my problem. I have a custom GroupBox, and inside of that is a custom picturebox and label.

The issue is, when I launch the form application whenever my mouse enters the GroupBox my my label's font color changes to black and my picture box seems to have "disappeared". I don't have a clue why that is.

GroupBox:

```
Class GhostGroupBox
    Inherits ThemeControl154

    Sub New()
        MyBase.New()
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw, True)
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.ContainerControl, True)
        DoubleBuffered = True
        BackColor = Color.Transparent
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub ColorHook()

    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub PaintHook()
        G.Clear(Color.FromArgb(60, 60, 60))
        Dim asdf As HatchBrush
        asdf = New HatchBrush(HatchStyle.DarkDownwardDiagonal, Color.FromArgb(35, Color.Black), Color.FromArgb(0, Color.Gray))
        G.FillRectangle(New SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(60, 60, 60)), New Rectangle(0, 0, Width, Height))
        asdf = New HatchBrush(HatchStyle.LightDownwardDiagonal, Color.DimGray)
        G.FillRectangle(asdf, 0, 0, Width, Height)
        G.FillRectangle(New SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(230, 20, 20, 20)), 0, 0, Width, Height)
        G.FillRectangle(New SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(70, Color.Black)), 1, 1, Width - 2, Me.CreateGraphics.MeasureString(Text, Font).Height + 8)

        G.DrawLine(New Pen(Color.FromArgb(90, 90, 90)), 1, Me.CreateGraphics.MeasureString(Text, Font).Height + 8, Width - 2, Me.CreateGraphics.MeasureString(Text, Font).Height + 8)

        DrawBorders(Pens.Black)
        DrawBorders(New Pen(Color.FromArgb(90, 90, 90)), 1)
        G.DrawString(Text, Font, Brushes.White, 5, 5)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Label & PictureBox (same code, just inherits the respective):

```
Public Class TransparentLabel
    Inherits Label

    Public Sub New()
        Me.SetStyle(ControlStyles.Opaque, True)
        Me.SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, False)
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides ReadOnly Property CreateParams() As CreateParams
        Get
            Dim parms As CreateParams = MyBase.CreateParams
            parms.ExStyle = parms.ExStyle Or &H20
            ' Turn on WS_EX_TRANSPARENT
            Return parms
        End Get
    End Property

End Class
```

Can someone see what's wrong? I tried commenting out the ControlBox's OnMouseMove, that didn't fix it. I also don't have any events set for the ControlBox.

Comment: Visual Basic wasn't a tag, VBA is Visual Basic Application so I thought that might be it. Sorry, I've removed the tag as I now re-read what VBA is.

Answer (score 3):

Without working code it’s hard to say, I have two suggestions:

1. Change `Invalidate` in `OnMouseMove` to `Invalidate(True)` so `GroupBox`'s children get refreshed too. Child controls might not get a paint message.
2. For a transparent control you should use `SetStyle(ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor Or ControlStyles.UserPaint, True)` In `OnHandleCreated` rather than setting the `ExStyle` in `CreateParams`. Plus `&H20` means `WS_EX_TRANSPARENT` while in the constructor you set the control to be opaque.

Comment: Firstly, welcome to Stack Overflow! I updated the OP, the code for the GroupBox before was the wrong code, not the code I was using. I added the `OnMouseMove` to the correct section because it didn't exist, and made it `Invalidate(True)`. That seems to work most of the time, but it's not 100% reliable. The 2nd option crashed Visual Basic 2012 Express completely. So this will work for now, but I'll wait to accept this answer to see if someone else has a better solution.

Comment: Just an FYI, your solution make it seem to flicker rapidly when I put my mouse in there, and when the mouse leaves most controls inside have disappeared.

Comment: Flicker usually means double buffering isn't enabled. I see you turned on DoubleBuffered but may I suggest good old fashioned SetStyle? Double buffering is only activated with UserPaint style flag and it may not be set.
On an unrelated note SetStyle should only be called after handle is created so constructor isn't a good place for it. OnHandleCreated?
For the MouseLeave part without working code I can't really tell.

Comment: I'm sorry, could you tell me what code I need to include? I'm a noob at design and things like this, and didn't understand much of what you just wrote.

Answer (score 1):

I have another suggestion - clone your project and try to simplify your code there, to a point where it still has the problem, but is generic enough that you can publish it here. Also, you did not describe what all your custom controls are supposed to do. Other than that, have you tried the following to reduce flickering?

```
SendMessage(Me.Handle, WM_SETREDRAW, False, 0) ' Turn OFF UI updates
```

and

```
SendMessage(Me.Handle, WM_SETREDRAW, True, 0) ' Turn ON UI updates
```

I am using it for custom dropdown control in my project and it works well.

`DoubleBuffered` is useless, according to my experience.

For `SendMessage` to be available, you need to import it from `user32`:

```
Private Const WM_SETREDRAW As Integer = &HB
Private Declare Function SendMessage Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageA" (ByVal handle As IntPtr, ByVal wMsg As Integer, ByVal wParam As Integer, ByVal lParam As Integer) As Integer
```

You would turn UI updates off before any processing inside `PaintHook` (the very first line), and turn it back on after all processing is done. Also need to call `Me.Refresh()` after `SendMessage(...True...)`, otherwise you would get no updates at all.

Comment: `SendMessage is not declared.` I put this right under `DoubleBuffered`, is this correct? Sorry I don't know much about stuff like this.

Comment: @DannyF247: You need to wrap your custom drawing with SendMessage lines, turning off and on UI updates respectively. I updated the answer with new information.

Comment: I've done exactly as you said, turned off updates at start of PaintHook, re-enabled at end of PaintHook and then did `Me.Refresh()`, but it still flickers :/ Any suggestions?

Comment: Create a POC (proof-of-concept) project and try to reproduce there. If you can, publish it here, maybe somebody will have a look. It's part of a regular debugging/troubleshooting procedure - and your responsibility as a programmer.